# How to render object data to table with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I got a data from API and it seems like Object data(JSON) [Public API Link](https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/all)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './PostContainer.css';

class PostContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { chartData: {} };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let { data: chartData } = await axios.get(
      'https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/all'
    );
    this.setState({ chartData });
  }

  render() {
    const { chartData } = this.state;
    // chartData.data.date = undefined;
    // delete chartData.data.date;
    console.log(`DATA ${chartData.data}`);

    // for (const val, index in chartData.data) {
    //   console.log(`${index} : ${val.sell_price}`)
    // }

    return (
      <div className="Post">
        <table id="table" className="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Coin Name</th>
              <th>Current Price</th>
              <th>Volume</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{?? What should I enter?}</td>
              <td>123123123123</td>
              <td>12312312</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>ETH</td>
              <td>121243123</td>
              <td>1231231</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostContainer;
```

And I want to render all data to table like this.

[image]

With console.log, it returned Object like this

[image]

But I don't have any idea how to iterate to render the data with these object data.
Before when I use Express & NodeJS & Pug environment I use for...in statement and it works well. But in Reactjs with this code

```
for (const val, index in chartData.data) {
      console.log(`${index} : ${val.sell_price}`)
    }
```

It got error like this

```
  Line 24:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

I tried lots of another iteration method but it seems not right.

Comment: `chartData` is array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to iterate the values `Object.entries()` can also do the trick just skip the key part.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(chartData.data)) {
  console.log(`${value.sell_price}`)
}

// Or, via forEach

Object.entries(chartData.data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${value.sell_price}`) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved the problem with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

The listed API `data` is an `object`. To iterate over the object and use the data as well as the `key`, first lets get the `keys` from the object(inside your `render`). This can be done using

```
const dataKeys = Object.keys(chartData);
```

Next, lets iterate over the keys and generate a `tr` and the `td` and display the required data. That would be similar to (inside your `tbody`)

```
{
  map(dataKeys, (k) => {
   const data = chartData[k];
    return (
       <tr>
          <td>{k}</td>
          <td>{data.sell_price}</td>
          <td>{data.units_traded}</td>
        </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Place the above code at the appropriate place. The logic used is, first get the `keys` of the object in an array. Then `map` over them and return the required `jsx` that would be added to the table body. Hope this helps.

Assumption: `data`(Object) in API points to `chartData` variable in the above code.